# Stackexchange app for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, application

Is there such a thing? I'm wondering because I'd like to get as many stand-alones as I can find.

Answer (score 4):

There is an official [Android app for Stack Exchange](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) with a Google Play Store rating of 4.5/5 by nearly 19,000 users and over 500,000 installs. The Play Store also an unofficial app with a lower rating and two orders of magnitude lesser users and reviewers, and a game called Stack Exchange, so be careful you get The Real Thing if you go to the Play Store. There's nothing specific for https://unix.stackexchange.com found in the Play Store and no app for Linux found when searching Debian and Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I'm using it (the Android app) now.